# Python Peewee resets primary key

Tags: python, peewee

In some situations, the Python module Peewee will reset the (non-integer) primary key when saving an object. I have constructed this example to clarify:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from peewee import *
import uuid

db = SqliteDatabase('./db/' + str(uuid.uuid4()) + '.db')

class A(Model):
    id = CharField(primary_key=True)
    def __init__(self):
        super(A, self).__init__()
        self.id = str(uuid.uuid4())
    class Meta:
        database = db

class B(A):
    name = CharField()    
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(B, self).__init__()
        self.name = name

A.create_table()
a = A()
print a.id
a.save(force_insert=True)
print a.id
print "--"    
B.create_table()
b = B(name='Test')
print b.id
b.save(force_insert=True)
print b.id
```

An example output:

```
$ ./pkey.py 
0bd49fa9-c5cc-40e7-aff7-24e0b17247cb
0bd49fa9-c5cc-40e7-aff7-24e0b17247cb
--
2fe23bac-4cb2-46a2-827a-8a1c6395e665
1
```

Now, the last line should not be 1, but rather 2fe... as the line above. The funny thing is, this, as the example shows, only happens to the child object.

Am I completely misunderstanding something here?

Comment: I posted a bug report [https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/issues/175](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/issues/175) on this - the developer recognizes the problem, and will look into it.

Comment: It is now fixed - should work in the next release. [https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/commit/69a295046ad9f1cfc38d2a1d4b688cfd25b2c65f](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/commit/69a295046ad9f1cfc38d2a1d4b688cfd25b2c65f)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have addressed this issue on GitHub and posted a fix.  The problem was caused by a bug in the inheritance of primary key fields from model to model.

https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/issues/175

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a peewee expert, but browsing a couple of samples ([example](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/example.html), [cookbook](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/cookbook.html)), these are classes that define your db schema and implement the database access but are not intended to implement your logic. It should be something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from peewee import *
import uuid

db = SqliteDatabase('./db/' + str(uuid.uuid4()) + '.db')

class A(Model):
    id = CharField(primary_key=True)
    class Meta:
        database = db

class B(A):
    name = CharField()    

A.create_table()
a = A.create(id=uuid.uuid4())
print a.id
a.save(force_insert=True)
print a.id
print "--"    
B.create_table()
 b = B.create(id=uuid.uuid4(), name='Test')
print b.id
b.save(force_insert=True)
print b.id
```

Look through the example and cookbook.

Comment: Well, the point of an object-relational-mapper is to let you easily store your model objects in a relational database, but if you can't use the objects for standard OOP stuff, then it kind of ruins the idea, doesn't it? I might be wrong, but I think it would be a terrible limitation.